# Backbone View bound to Collection Not Adding

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

As far as I can tell, I have bound a collection to a view. However, when I add things to that collection, the code that is meant to run on the add event is not being triggered.

In the parent view I have this -

```
   _searchHistoryLoaded:(data)=>
    console.log("in search hist loaded")
    console.log(searchHistory)
    searchHistoryView = new pt.SearchHistory(pastSearches:data,collection:searchHistory)
    searchHistory.add(someModel)
```

In the child view I have

```
@collection.on "add", (toAdd)->
  console.log("inside @collection add")
```

But @collection add is never printed.

Am I binding correctly?

Comment: Where did you create the instance of your collection? Where `searchHistory` comes from?

Comment: searchHistory is created as an instance variable

Comment: so I do searchHistory = new pt.SomeCollection() right below class pt.View extends Backbone.View

Comment: Please add some more code, your problem is still not clear to me.